# How to parse String "06\24\1989" into Date 06/24/1989 format using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

How to parse String "06\24\1989" (if user entered like this) in to Date format (MM/DD/YYYY) using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: by writing some code.. did youu write any ?

Comment: Simplest way: `"09\24\1989".replace("\\", "/");`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the `String` into a `Date` and another one to transform it back to a `String` in the format you want. Remember to use double backslashes in string literals (`\` is an escape character)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("MM\\dd\\yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdfFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try{
    Date date = sdfParse.parse("09\\24\\1989");
    System.out.println(sdfFormat.format(date)); // Prints 09/24/1989
}
catch (ParseException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid date");
}
```

Of course you could just replace all backslashes to forward slashes, and try to parse it with a `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");` if you want to validate it is a valid date.

```
String input = "09\\24\\1989".replace("\\", "/");
SimpleDateFormat sdfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("MM\\dd\\yyyy");    
try{
    sdfFormat.parse(input))
}
catch (ParseException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid date");
}
```

Comment: for replaceAll you need 4 slashes, not 2. `replaceAll("\\\\", "/");`

Comment: Indeed! Fixed answer. Anyway the intent of the answer wasn't to provide ready-to-c&p code, particulary given the OP hasn't shown any research effort at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String dateString = "09\\24\\1989";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM\\DD\\YYYY");
    Date myDate = format.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    //what you want
}
```